nodejs/sharp: applying a 5x4 color matrix filter
I have a RN image cropper/resizer/filter applier (https://snack.expo.dev/@leurs247/cropper). This works. Please test on your device because the web version on the expo website doesn't work.
Current workflow: an image is uploaded to an S3 bucket, together with the translateX/Y values, rotate value and scale value. On the server, the image is converted with sharp.
I have now added filters (see the snack for details). The problem is: I have no idea how to apply the same filters server-side. For example, this is the Juno-filter in react-native-skia:
    Juno: [
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        -0.4, 1.3, -0.4, 0.2, -0.1,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    ]

How can I apply the same effect in sharp? Or is there another option I could try, like applying the filter to the image before it's uploaded (client-side in my RN app).
I also found this (https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-operation#recomb) on the sharp website, but it's only for 3x3 and 4x4 color matrix, and skia uses a 5x4 matrix.
